# Getting 404 with netlify form (VueJs 3 + Vite + VueRouter + Netlify)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, netlify, netlify-form

I have this form in my ContactView.vue page `src/views/ContactView.vue` :
and I want to redirect to a custom page thanking for the message `src/views/SuccessView.vue`

```
            <form name="contact-form" action="/success" method="POST" data-netlify="true" data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field">
              <input type="hidden" name="contact-form" value="contact-form" />
              <div class="grid md:grid-cols-2 md:gap-6">
                <div class="relative z-0 w-full mb-6 group">
                    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="floating_first_name" class="block py-2.5 px-0 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-transparent border-0 border-b-2 border-pine appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 focus:border-bubblegum peer" placeholder=" " required />
                    <label for="first_name" class="peer-focus:font-medium absolute text-sm text-gray-500 duration-300 transform -translate-y-6 scale-75 top-3 -z-10 origin-[0] peer-focus:left-0 peer-focus:text-bubblegum  peer-placeholder-shown:scale-100 peer-placeholder-shown:translate-y-0 peer-focus:scale-75 peer-focus:-translate-y-6">First name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="relative z-0 w-full mb-6 group">
                    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="floating_last_name" class="block py-2.5 px-0 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-transparent border-0 border-b-2 border-pine appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 focus:border-bubblegum peer" placeholder=" " required />
                    <label for="last_name" class="peer-focus:font-medium absolute text-sm text-gray-500 duration-300 transform -translate-y-6 scale-75 top-3 -z-10 origin-[0] peer-focus:left-0 peer-focus:text-bubblegum  peer-placeholder-shown:scale-100 peer-placeholder-shown:translate-y-0 peer-focus:scale-75 peer-focus:-translate-y-6">Last name</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="relative z-0 w-full mb-6 group">
                  <input type="email" name="email" id="floating_email" class="block py-2.5 px-0 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-transparent border-0 border-b-2 border-pine appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 focus:border-bubblegum peer" placeholder=" " required />
                  <label for="email" class="peer-focus:font-medium absolute text-sm text-gray-500 duration-300 transform -translate-y-6 scale-75 top-3 -z-10 origin-[0] peer-focus:left-0 peer-focus:text-bubblegum  peer-placeholder-shown:scale-100 peer-placeholder-shown:translate-y-0 peer-focus:scale-75 peer-focus:-translate-y-6">Email address</label>
              </div>

              <div class="relative z-0 w-full mb-6 group">
                  <textarea type="text" name="textarea" id="floating_ext_area" class="block py-2.5 px-0 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-transparent border-0 border-b-2 border-pine appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 focus:border-bubblegum peer" placeholder=" " required />
                  <label for="textarea" class="peer-focus:font-medium absolute text-sm text-gray-500 duration-300 transform -translate-y-6 scale-75 top-3 -z-10 origin-[0] peer-focus:left-0 peer-focus:text-bubblegum  peer-placeholder-shown:scale-100 peer-placeholder-shown:translate-y-0 peer-focus:scale-75 peer-focus:-translate-y-6">Your Message</label>
              </div>

              <button type="submit" class="text-white bg-bubblegum hover:bg-cherry focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-cotton-candy font-medium rounded-lg text-sm w-full sm:w-auto px-5 py-2.5 text-center">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

[image: black screen]

I followed every guide on there and on the related forum but none ot the asnwers could help me.

i read about [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72462309/react-error-404-on-form-submit-with-netlify-forms) but seems it does not work for me.

Most of the guides and tutorial refers to having and exact HTML clone as a skeleton in the "public" HTML so in the index.html I've done sometinh similar

```
<body>
    <form netlify netlify-honeypot="bot-field" hidden name="contact-form" value="contact-form" method="POST" action="/success" >
      <input type="text" name="first_name" />
      <input type="text" name="last_name" />
      <input type="email" name="email" />
      <textarea name="textarea"></textarea>
      <button type="submit"></button>
    </form>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
  </body>
```

When I try to fill out my form in the `random-netlify-name-784120.netlify.app` as soon as I fill out the form, I get a black screen with this respone.

How can I make averything work?

[image: POST]

Answer (score 0):

did you get this working?
I had similar issue and only resolved by removing `action='/success/'` parameter and let Netlify redirect to it's own page...

custom ajax isn't working either because the fetch to `'/'` returns 404...

still trucking away at either a custom page or a custom handler... i'll post back if I find something.

(I'm using Vite + React + Netlify) w/ no router package...
I was able to get a `pages/success` page with this in my `vite.config.ts`

```
build: {
    ...,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: resolve(root, 'index.html'),
        success: resolve(root, 'pages', 'success', 'index.html'),
      },
    }
```

Comment: Lucky you. I'm using Vite+Sveltekit. Both custom page & handler didn't work here.